# how to play a sound after posting a new record in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm new in asp.net core

I created a post method in the controller ([HttpPost])
and after posting , I created a view that shows all the records.
is there an easy way to play a sound when a new record is posted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SignalR to push real-time notifications in your list view. It allows server code to send asynchronous notifications to client-side web applications. Basically, the idea is after inserting a new record into DB you will push a message using SignalR and it'll reflect in the client panel immediately.

Here is the example:

Notification Hub

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
}
```

Add it in `Startup`

```
public class Startup
{

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notfHub"); // <====== add this ======
        });

    }
}
```

In client side (notification.js)

```
"use strict";
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notfHub").build();
connection.on("sendNotification", (data) => {
    alert(data)
});
connection.start().catch(function (err) {
       return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

So when you insert new entity you can send new notification after insertion and it'll be pushed in the client side.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _notificationHubContext;
    public AdminController(IHubContext<NotificationHub> notificationHubContext)
    {
        _notificationHubContext = notificationHubContext;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Add(User model)
    {
        // add your db insertion operation here
        await _notificationHubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("sendNotification", model);
        return View();
    }
}
```

[For more details check here](https://www.zealousweb.com/signalr-to-send-real-time-notifications-with-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for the codes , i did follow your codes but i have an issue with this one 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>

i think because im useing 2.2 net core

Comment: You're welcome, Please upvote or accept the answer if it helps you. Btw Yes, from here you will find the instructions for SignalR with .net core 2.0 https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-2-0-uses-signalr-technology/